# How to set opacity only for the parent?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My structure looks like this:

[image]

The situation: I need to make a transparent background. So I add opacity to the container:

```
.container{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9de;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

The main problem is that all childs also are 0.5 transparent. How to set the `.box` with 100% white background with no opacity?

Like this http://www.wix.com/demone2/street-photography-b#!blog/crkt Photo -> transparent block -> white block

Comment: Use `rgba` - `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7rL49ax/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the colour including the alpha channel using the [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29) notation.

In this case, you could use something like `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)` (the same settings as the site you link to). It's generally good practice to provide an `rgb()` alternative for browsers that don't support `rgba` (even though that's now fairly few).

```
.container{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9de;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```